# Why is a positive cone defined the way it is?

Tags: field-theory, definition, ordered-fields

Let $K$ be a field. Consider $P \subseteq K$ satisfying the following properties:

> 1. $x \in P$ and $y \in P$ imply $x+y \in P$ and $xy \in P$
> 2. $x \in K$ imply $x^2 \in P$
> 3. ${-1} \notin P$

We call such $P$ a prepositive cone. We further call $P$ a positive cone if $K = P \cup {-P}$.

I have a few questions regarding the notion of a positive cone (I have not found references for this concept elsewhere other than Wikipedia).

1. Why the name positive "cone"? I understand why positive is there, but not the "cone" part.
2. If we keep Property $1$, delete Property $2$ and Property $3$, and add Property $2'$, which says that $x \in P$, or $x = 0$, or $x \notin P$ (only one case holds for any $x \in K$), and define a positive cone this way, what do we lose? Why not define positive cones this way instead?

Comment: In your second question, do you mean to delete "$K = P \cup -P$" (maybe call this property 4) too? Or otherwise, do you mean to define a *pre*positive cone?

Comment: Also, are you sure you do not want "$x \in P$ or $x\in -P$" in your property 2', that is, basically property 2' is property 4? The way you have it, $P=\Bbb{R}^+$ or $P=\Bbb{Z}$ or even $P=\Bbb{N}$ in $K =\Bbb{C}$ satisfy properties 1 and 2'. -- Finally, there is a minor technical issue with $0$, I think here property 2 necessitates $0 \in P$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I asked the question last year without any background in field theory (or even basic modern algebra, for that matter), because I wanted a treatment of ordering $\mathbf{R}$ that is different from the usual $\leq$ axioms. I tried very hard to search for an easy reference on positive cones, but did not find any, so I abandoned the topic. My initial question was of course riddled with errors. Anyway, if you're willing to show me a good source for beginners, or explain what a prepositive cone/positive cone is, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I know see that I got the definitions wrong. Let $K$ be a field, and $P' \subseteq K$ be closed under addition, multiplication, and taking squares, and $-1 \notin P'$. We call $P'$ a prepositive cone of $K$. Now by Zorn's Lemma we can extend the prepositive cones of $K$ to a maximal set $P$, which has the property that $K = P \cup -P$, and we call $P$ the positive cone of $K$.

Comment: In elementary analysis, we can order $\mathbf{R}$ by specifying a special set $P$ (called the set of positive reals) which is closed under addition and multiplication, and every real is either in $P$, $-P$, or zero. I would expect that the concept of a positive cone by defined this way, but in algebra this is not the case, because we need to define prepositive cones, extend those to a maximal one to get a positive cone. Why go through all the trouble? This means that the prepositive cone concept is more than a generalisation of the set of positive reals, but I don't know what it generalises.

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't have said "closed under taking squares".

Comment: I do not know answers to most of your questions. The wikipedia article on this topic references T.-Y. Lam's book on quadratic forms, so I would start to look there (I find Lam's books very good to read in general). I'd like to point out (and this is sort of an answer to your second original question) that indeed $K = P\cup -P$ with property 1 implies property 2, and if we further assume $P\cap -P \subset \{0\}$ (or even just $P \neq K$), we also get property 3.

Comment: I would like to see an example of a prepositive cone that is not a positive cone. Is the additive semigroup generated by the squares in $\Bbb{Q}$ smaller than the whole $\Bbb{Q}^+$? Then that would be an example.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> A set $C$ is called a “cone” with vertex at the origin if for any $x\in C$ and any scalar $a\ge0$, $ax\in C$.

Look familiar? There is a related concept of a cone for linear algebra.

> A cone $C$ is a convex cone if $ax + by$ belongs to $C$, for any positive scalars $a,b$ and any vectors $x, y$ in $C$.

That should also look familiar.

If you look at the Wikipedia page, you’ll see these actually look like cones.

> [image: three-vector cone]
>
> Convex cone generated by the conic combination of three black vectors.